# Nginx and proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a problem. I have 2 servers and 2 domains, I want to setup redirect from one to another. When I do it, I see 404 error no matter what I do. I don`t even see requests on the second server. I can ping/curl from first to the second server and get data.

centos-release-6-9.el6.12.3.i686
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
TLS SNI support enabled

Nginx conf related to this task:

```
  location ~* ^/folder1/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/(.*)\.txt$ {
   resolver 127.0.0.1 1.1.1.1;
   proxy_intercept_errors on;
   proxy_set_header Host domain1.com;
   proxy_set_header Referrer domain1.com;
   proxy_set_header User-Agent 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0';
   proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
   proxy_pass http://domain2.com/folder2/$1/$2/$3.txt;
   proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
   root $root_path;
   error_page 404 = @fallback;
  }
```

I thought problem-related to a resolver, I tried some combinations and it gives nothing. My experience is small.

Comment: Do you have a DNS resolver on `127.0.0.1` or `1.1.1.1`?  You should not normally need to set `resolver` in nginx unless you want the web server to use a different DNS resolver then the host it is running on.

Comment: Isnt resolver is like DNS? I thought its like DNS servers. If I remove this string, I get 502 error from nginx on request.

Comment: The nginx `resolver` setting tells nginx to use a specific DNS resolver, which would require that a DNS service is listening at the specified location.  I just noticed that `1.1.1.1` does have a DNS service offered by cloudflare.  Anything in either of the server's nginx logs for that 502 error?  A 502 Bad Gateway error usually means that nginx had some sort of issue with the server listed in `proxy_pass`.  Have you verified that you can reach `domain2.com` from the `domain1.com` server?

Comment: error log: `2018/05/04 10:54:07 [error] 24144#0: *703343 no resolver defined to resolve domain2, client: myip, server: domain1, request: "GET /folder1/1/2/3.mp3 HTTP/1.1", host: "domain1", referrer: "http://domain1/myscript.php` . It tells my nothing about what to do:( And yes, i can ping/curl from server1 to server2/domain2

Answer (score 1):

I just an idiot. I just changed conf part to:

`proxy_set_header Host domain2.com;`

And now it works. Thanks, GracefulRestart, I just googled this error and it clearly told me to use domain2 instead of domain1 in my config.